# "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using *Android Studio* until I updated to 0.2.6. Now, I can't compile or create a new project.

**What happens?**
I am not sure but I think *Android Studio* does not know where is my sdk folder (I mean sdk folder that is into my android studio directory).

**What I did?**
I have opened Android Studio as administrator (`right click > open as administrator`).
Then I go to `Configure > Projects Defaults > Project Structure`.
I have only a SDK (path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`). I haven't set my SDK then I click to add and I find my sdk (sdk folder that is into android studio directory).

Ok... result: The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK.

*What can i do?*

Comment: Adding any errors you get to your post would also help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the instructions on the [install page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)?

> Known issue: On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not
>   find where Java is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need
>   to set an environment variable indicating the correct location. Select
>   Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System
>   Properties. Then open Advanced tab > Environment Variables and add a
>   new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for
>   example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21.

Make sure you have a JAVA_HOME environment variable point to the correct path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 in your case)

Comment: I have that environment variable. I have fixed my error doing:
Unistalling by Ccleaner.
Cleaning my register.
Installing Android Studio from zero in another directory.
Now, everything is working.
PS: I have changed my sdk path (into my project).

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it for Mac?