# How to create Java 8 project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-8.1, java-8

I want to try IntelliJ IDEA 13.1, so I've installed the enterprise edition for evaluation. Also, I have installed JDK8u11 64 bit. I am using Windows 8.1.

When I try to create new project, I need to select JDK. I am able to choose JDK7, but JDK8 is not accepted with message "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK".

[image: Error window]

Based on ["The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK" Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500218/the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk-android-studio) I've set JAVA_HOME to point to C:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0 where JDK8u11 is installed, with no effect. I have also run IntelliJ IDEA in Administrator mode, without success.

I'm a bit stuck here. Am I missing something?

Comment: 1. Did you add the `JAVA_HOME` to `PATH` environment variable? 2. Did you `restart` your PC after changing the `JAVA_HOME` value? 3. Is `Java 8` the only entry in `JAVA_HOME` value?

Comment: Did U tried it with `eclipse`?

Comment: Yes, I have, Eclipse (STS) detected it automatically based on JAVA_HOME, new project started properly, no errors or problems.
Just wondering - perhaps IntelliJ IDEA works only with specific updates of JDK and jdk8u11 is not supported yet?

Comment: Try to download `Intellij Idea 14` with bundled `java 8`: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP

Comment: Thank you, I will. Yet I am still hoping to understand why and IDE officially supporting Java 8 does not accept Java 8 as JDK :)

Comment: You do not need to have IDEA run under Java 8 to create and build a Java 8 project. I currently have several Java 8 projects in IDEA 13 with IDEA 13 running via a Java 7 JDK. There is just something about that JDK installation that IDEA is not liking. Possibly a missing or corrupt file. I recommend just reinstalling the Java 8 JDK. You can also look in the IDEA log (Help > Show Log) to see if there is any additional information logged as to the problem. p.s. you do not need to set JAVA_HOME. IDEA does not use that env variable. If it did, you'd have to change it constantly.

Comment: p.p.s make sure the dir you select has the bin, jre and lib dir. perhaps you have a double jdk1.8.0 dir name (or some such thing) from an error when setting the install dir during install.

Comment: Thanks @MarkVedder. You've touched one presumably key aspect - I have noticed that JDK8 gave me an option to install JRE8, but did not ask where to do it and installed it in a different location. I will clear it up and reinstall JDK8.

Comment: @MarkVedder: Please copy your jre folder hint into an answer - I'd like to select it as a valid one. I uninstalled only jre (left jdk) and installed it again, but this time selected the jre folder under JDK location (in my case C:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre). I ran IDEA with regular rights (no administrator) and it successfully accepted JDK as a valid one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A copy of my answer in the comments so that @tptak can graciously give me credit for the correct answer. Thanks.*

Make sure the dir you select has the `bin`, `jre` and `lib` directories. Could you have a double jdk1.8.0 dir name (or some such thing) from an error when setting the install dir during install?

Comment: Just a copy of comments:
Thanks @MarkVedder. You've touched one presumably key aspect - I have noticed that JDK8 gave me an option to install JRE8, but did not ask where to do it and installed it in a different location. I will clear it up and reinstall JDK8.

Comment: Just a copy of comments:  I uninstalled only jre (left jdk) and installed it again, but this time selected the jre folder under JDK location (in my case C:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre). I ran IDEA with regular rights (no administrator) and it successfully accepted JDK as a valid one. Thank You!